# Columnas invisibles en Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Espero hoy sea un día lleno de bendiciones para todos ustedes.

Les comento amigos que estoy tomando clases de Bootstrap y como reto personal quiero lograr este diseño.

[image: diseño]

Donde los contenedores amarillos serían las *"columnas invisibles"*, las cuales estoy manejando con la clase .d-none que las oculta.

Los contenedores grises superiores tienen el mismo ancho.

Creo que esty muy cerca de lograrlo pero por alguna razon mi código no se ve como la imagen. Que fallas tengo? Esta es la forms correcta de hacerlo? Como juntaría los bloques grises?

Este es mi código:

```css
.caja{  
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

.gris{
  background: grey;
}

.ylw{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>      
        
    <div class="col-md-3 caja ylw d-none"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja ylw d-none"></div>
       
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja ylw d-none"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
      
    <div class="col-md-3 caja ylw d-none"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja ylw d-none"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja ylw d-none"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
      
    </div>
 </div>
```

Mil gracias hermanos!

Comment: te sugiero que uses tambien los cierres del div class "row", recuerda que cada row "fila" posee doce columnas o deben sumar ello..

Comment: Tu código es sólo con fines didácticos? Podría modificar el código para que se vea como la imagen?

Comment: @DiegoAvila si, tengo 16 filas. Porqué deberían ser 12?

Comment: @JheymanMejia Es un reto personal sobre el uso del grid layout, se podria cambiar pero si es Bootstrap

Comment: @ConceptDev no tienes 16 filas, tienes 16 contenedores que ocupan 48 columnas de 12 disponibles. Revisa: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: porque no ocupas simplemente asi: "d-none col-md-3 caja ylw"

Comment: dentro de la documentacion explica que "d-none" oculta para todo tamaño de pantalla , si deseas especificar para cierto tamaño usa como lo dice la documentacion: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Comment: Trabaja con offsets en las columnas, esa es la forma indicada de hacerlo

Comment: @JheymanMejia en la documentacion dice que offsets oculta las columnas que se indican? No termino de comprender su uso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando bootstrap debería ser así

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3  caja gris"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3  caja gris"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3  caja gris"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3  caja gris"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-6 caja gris"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3  caja gris"></div>
        <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-md-9 col-md-3  caja gris"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: se me fueron esos rows en mi respuesta xD

Comment: Me gusta tu respuesta, pero no termino de entender el funcionamiento de la clase offset

Comment: Son columnas con la clase .d-none?

Comment: Básicamente la clase .col-md-offset-* para desplazar cualquier columna hacia su derecha. Estas clases aumentan el tamaño del margen izquierdo de la columna en una cantidad equivalente a esas * columnas. La clase .col-md-offset-4 por ejemplo desplaza la columna una anchura equivalente a 4 columnas. @ConceptDev

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta hermano. Bendiciones

Answer (score 2):

Aqui lo hice, espero te sirva :D

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Prueba</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="gris caja"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="gris caja"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="gris caja"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="gris caja"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="amarillo caja"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="gris caja"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="amarillo caja"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="gris caja"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="amarillo caja"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="gris caja"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="amarillo caja"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="gris caja"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    <style>
      .caja {
  height:50px;
  border-radius:3rem;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  }
  .gris {
    background: grey;
  }
  .amarillo {
    background: yellow;
    display: none; /* Poner o quitar para ver o no columnas */
  }
  .row {
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
  }
    </style>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Prueba de codepen.io con botones para mostrar/ocultar las columnas amarillas: https://codepen.io/PatrickDyD/full/mgbpQe

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo Patrick, lo agradezco enormemente

Comment: No hay problema amigo! Para eso estamos

Answer (score 1):

De partida si quieres que se vean los divs que tienes ocultos con *d-none* como en la imagen, tienes que sacarlos, algo de logica.

Y pensando que bootstrap la grilla es de 12 elementos en donde tu vez como los agrupas una respuesta sería esta

```css
.caja{  
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

.gris{
  background: grey;
}

.ylw{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>      
        
    <div class="col-md-3 caja ylw "></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja ylw "></div>
       
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja ylw "></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
      
    <div class="col-md-9 caja ylw "></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 caja gris"></div>
      
    </div>
 </div>
 


</body>
</html>
```

Pensando en que quieres que estas cajas se vean como en la imagen

Comment: Gracias caballero por su pronta respuesta, pero deseo ocultar los contenedores amarillos

Comment: entonces agregales el *d-none* y con eso, a pesar de que estén ocultos, vas a tener los divs del tamaño que muestras en tu imagen